# PHP file get contents with URL returns getaddrinfo failure

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

I am trying to get the (pre-processed) content of an external PHP file:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.org/myfile.php');
```

When I do this, I get an error:

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/...localfile.php on line 13

And:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.org/myfile.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.../localfile.php on line 13

Any ideas what I could do?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I do have allow_url_fopen set to "On".

Comment: do you have allow_url_fopen = On in your php.ini?

Comment: This is most likely a DNS issue.

Comment: You could be in safe_mode which disables allow_url_fopen too, use cURL instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use cURL...

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $return;
}


$string = curl('http://www.example.org/myfile.php'); //string with data
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out whether it works - as soon as I can :D
By the way: `curl_close($ch)` is an unreachable statement ^^

Comment: No it's not :) Only exit() will terminate function.